# how to find common element in array with duplicates ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Lets say array look like below

```
city = ['london', 'new york', 'london', 'london', 'washington']

desired_location = ['london']
```

`city & desired_location` gives `['london']`

but I want `['london', 'london', 'london']`

Comment: Ok, you have some ambition/goal. Now you need to tell SO what you need help with, where you are stuck.

Comment: Basically, I need to take common element from two array and take top repeated element from common element.

Comment: @HariKrishnan, You have to be very specific about what you need. From your example, all that we can say is get all objects from `city`, which is also present in `desired_locations`. That is exactly what my solution does. You have not mentioned anything about top repeated elements, in your question. We could not have guessed that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

```
city.select {|c| desired_location.include?(c)}
# => ["london", "london", "london"]
```

Comment: i think this will work, but both array will contain 1000 + element. is it feasible ?

Comment: compare with desired location ?, what Santhosh put works. city.select {|c| desired_location.include?(c)} will return ['london', 'london', 'london']. If desired_location is desired_location = ['london', 'new york'], you would get ["london", "new york", "london", "london"]

Comment: What didn't work? What happened when you tried it? Did you have a typo or syntax error? This should work.

Comment: when i tried this. it didn't get repeated element from first array. lemme try again.

Answer (score 1):

```
cities = ['london', 'new york', 'london', 'london', 'washington']
```

If `desired_location` contains a single element:

```
desired_location = ['london']
```

I recommend @santosh's solution, but this also works:

```
desired_location.flat_map { |c| [c]*cities.count(c) }
  #=> ["london", "london", "london"]
```

Suppose `desired_location` contains multiple elements (which I assume is a possibility, for otherwise there would be no need for it to be an array):

```
desired_location = ['london', 'new york']
```

@Santosh' method returns:

```
["london", "new York", "london", "london"]
```

which is quite possibly what you want. If you'd prefer that they be grouped:

```
desired_location.flat_map { |c| [c]*cities.count(c) }
  #=> ["london", "london", "london", "new york"]
```

or:

```
desired_location.map { |c| [c]*cities.count(c) }
  #=> [["london", "london", "london"], ["new york"]]
```

Depending on your requirements, you might find it more useful to produce a hash:

```
Hash[desired_location.map { |c| [c, cities.count(c)] }]
  #=> {"london"=>3, "new york"=>1}
```

Comment: thanks @cary, let me try and reply you back. seems it will work. from final hash, is it finally sorted. I mean, first element will always be top ?

Comment: As long as you are using Ruby v1.9+, the keys of the hash at the end are guaranteed to be ordered as they are in `desired_location`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
cities = ['london', 'new york', 'london', 'london', 'washington']
puts cities.select{|city| cities.count(city) > 1}
```